# On click show random image(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create some sort of slide show based thing where when an image is clicked it replaces itself with a random image from a list of files. I've gotten the slideshow to work but it doesn't start with an image, instead I get a small square at the top, left corner of my screen.

Here is my code so far.

Function code:

```
<script>
function pickimg2() {
    var imagenumber = 2;
    var randomnumber = Math.random();
    var rand1 = Math.round( (imagenumber-1) * randomnumber) + 1;
    images = new Array;
    images[0] = "images2/pic1.png";
    images[1] = "images2/pic1.png";
    images[2] = "images2/pic2.png";
    var image = images[rand1];
    document.randimg.src = image;
}
</script>
```

Html code:

```
<body onload="pickimg2">

<a href="" onClick="pickimg();return false;"><IMG SRC="YOUR IMAGE1" name="randimg1" border=0></a>

</body>
```

Comment: images = new Array shd be images = new Array();

Comment: Set a valid url for your first image instead of `<IMG SRC="YOUR IMAGE1"`

Comment: Check your browser console.  I'm sure it's trying to tell you that there are errors in this JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It starts with a square since your first image defined has an invalid url:

```
<IMG SRC="YOUR IMAGE1" name="randimg1" border=0>
```

It Should be :

```
<img src="image1.jpg" name="randimg1" border=0>
```

Answer (score 0):

either give the source image path in IMAGE tag , else create a div and set it background property as image  file. IMG tag needs src property even if u dont use it.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like below.

Function code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function pickimg2(){
var imagenumber = 2 ;
var randomnumber = Math.random() ;
var rand1 = Math.round( (imagenumber-1) * randomnumber) + 1;
images = new Array();
images[0] = "images2/pic1.png";
images[1] = "images2/pic1.png";
images[2] = "images2/pic2.png";
var image = images[rand1];
document.randimg.src = image;
}
</script>
```

Html code:

```
<body onload="pickimg2">
<a href="" onClick="pickimg();return false;"><img src="images2/pic1.png" name="randimg" border=0></a>
</body>
```